# WebappClassLoader memory leak even with no gc roots

Tags: java, tomcat, memory-leaks, classloader, yourkit

[**HERE IS THE HEAD DUMP (UPDATED ON 10/29/2013)**](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/9210700/java_pid9478.hprof)

I'm working in a webapp with:

- Tomcat 7.0.24
- Java 6
- Spring 3 (with aop - cglib)
- SLF4J over Log4j
- Oracle Coherence

After a lot of work, I managed to remove all the strong reference to the class loader and now it is a candidate for the garbage collector. So, memory leak solved? Of course not! Because after several hot deployments a OOME appears due to PermGen space.

Thanks to Yourkit, I was able to check that the `WebappClassLoader` was *Pending Finalization* which means that is waiting in the finalizer queue (actually, is not the `WebappClassLoader` itself but one of his *referents*). Checking a memory snapshot I found several `Finalizer` references to Oracle Coherence classes...
[image]

This seems "okey": Coherence objects are waiting to be garbage collected thanks to all the hard work done removing all the strong references (killing all coherence threads, removing java security providers, etc). I think that there is nothing to do here.

So, I was thinking about some `finalize` execution that breaks something and then not allowing empty the finalizer queue. But the weird thing is that using JMX or `jmap -finalizerinfo` the finalizer queue seems to be empty! All this is very confusing so I kept searching in other places...

**Do you think that is something to do here?** I've read something about [CGLIB enhancing the `finalize` method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6517348/cglib-methodinterceptor-finalize). If I have access to `Enhancer` I can create a callback filter as explained [here](http://neopatel.blogspot.fr/2012/12/cglib-enhancer-and-finalize-method.html) but I dunno how to manage this with Spring AOP.

Well, searching in other places, I found several weak references from `java.lang.reflect.Proxy`. These are jdk dynamic proxies right? or they are related to Introspection memory leaks? with weak references?

[image]

INFO: I'm using a Spring's context listener that flushes instrospector's caches (`java.beans.Introspector.flushCaches()`). **What else I can do with this?**

Lets continue.

Then, we have several other weak references from `java.io.ObjectStreamClass$Caches`. A lot of my business objects have these kind of weak references.

[image]
[image]

Maybe I need flushing these caches. **But how??**

Then we have these weak reference related to `com.sun.internal.ResourceManager`, `java.util.logging.Logging` and `java.lang.reflect.Proxy`

[image]

**What I can do with this weak references? Do I need to worry about this or the problem is on the finalizer queue?** Any clue will be of help ... really :-D

Ah, another thing, I found a weak reference from a tomcat "main" thread that will not be renewed ever by tomcat. I know that my application can leave some thread local var in some tomcat threads, but [tomcat 7 renew these threads to avoid class loader memory leaks](http://wiki.apache.org/tomcat/MemoryLeakProtection#threadLocalPseudoLeak).
[image]

**I think this is the oddest thing on my memory snapshot, but is a weak referece right? What I can do with this?**

**EDIT:** Reading the [`java.lang.ref` javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/ref/package-summary.html) i found this:

> An object is weakly reachable if it is neither strongly nor softly reachable but can be reached by traversing a weak reference. When the weak references to a weakly-reachable object are cleared, the object becomes eligible for finalization.

So, **can weak references retain objects in the heap when they implement a `finalize` method?**

Meanwhile i found an answer to this, I manage to remove all the weak references to my classloader but two: `ClassLoaderLogManager.classLoaderLoggers` and the one related to the tomcat thread.

*NOTE:* Actually, I managed to remove the first one but this reference is set again by tomcat after/during undeployment.

**EDIT: PLUMBR RESULTS**

I've tried plumbr and no reports on the web console. Only this message on the standard output

```
Dumping heap to /opt/tomcat7/headdumps/java_pid9478.hprof ...
Heap dump file created [348373628 bytes in 3.984 secs]
#
# An unexpected error has been detected by Java Runtime Environment:
#
#  Internal Error (javaCalls.cpp:40), pid=9478, tid=1117813056
#  Error: guarantee(!thread->is_Compiler_thread(),"cannot make java calls from the compiler")
#
# Java VM: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (11.2-b01 mixed mode linux-amd64) [thread 1110444352 also had an error]
# An error report file with more information is saved as:
# [thread 1110444352 also had an error]
#
# If you would like to submit a bug report, please visit:
#   http://java.sun.com/webapps/bugreport/crash.jsp
#
******************************************************************************
*                                                                            *
* Plumbr has noticed that JVM has thrown an OutOfMemoryError: PermGen space. *
*                                                                            *
* You can increase PermGen size with -XX:MaxPermSize parameter.              *
* If you encountered this error after a redeploy, please read next article:  *
* http://plumbr.eu/blog/what-is-a-permgen-leak                               *
*                                                                            *
******************************************************************************
```

Comment: Do you have a heap dump after the OOM happened available somewhere for download? May be we would be able to look into it.

Comment: Hey @Nikem! That will be very nice! I've also tried with plumbr without any success :-( Here is the dump:
https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/9210700/java_pid12165.hprof

Comment: Have you tried to redeploy your application while having Plumbr attached? If you like, you can contact us at support@plumbr.eu in order to investigate why Plumbr has issue with this case.

Comment: I've already installed plumbr and I managed to use it, but not memory leak was detected! I'll try again. I'll keep you posted!

Comment: I recommend the following steps: start your application with Plumbr attached, run it for some time, redeploy the application, let Plumbr think for about 5 minutes. If does not help, please contact us :)

Comment: I've tried plumbr and nothing. Even my application does not appear on the plumbr web console after the OOME. Maybe I missed something. Can you help me ot understand how to use plumbr to find my leak? Thx in advance!

Answer (score 3):

I think Yourkit has led you to the wrong path.

I have looked into your heap dump using Eclipse Memory Analyzer. It showed, that WebappClassLoader is referenced by class com.inovasoftware.iap.data.access.platform.datarepository.CoherenceDataRepository$$EnhancerByCGLIB$$180c0a4e, which instance is alive in some thread local variable. Some googling showed this:
https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-2481

So may be upgrading Hibernate version will be of help.

[image: MAT screenshot]

Comment: Thanks for this info! I'll kill that reference right now! I'll keep you posted!

Comment: Hey @Nikem! Thanks for this finding! I managed to release the thread local but the class loader still "Pending Finalization" (on yourkit). I've also checked with EMA and I saw only Finalizer references to some Coherence Objects. If you can, take a look to the new head dump https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/9210700/Tomcat-2013-10-25.hprof

Comment: I will look into it. Do you still get OOM?

Comment: Yeap ... After 3/4 hot deployments. Thanks in advance btw :-)

Comment: That is strange. I cannot see any duplicated class loaders. There is only one WebappClassLoader for your application. Was this dump takes from a couple of redeploys? It looks very fresh to me.

Comment: Yeap, that one was taken only starting and stopping the application. But the result is the same: A WebappClassLoader with started=false that is never collected. I'll update the memory dump with that one generated after the OOME. Thanks btw

Comment: This is the dump after the OOME https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/9210700/java_pid9478.hprof. Sorry for the delay! (PS: I've deleted a previos comment because it was pointing to a non existent dump)